# how do i show a splash screen only when the activity starts up not when it is resumed?

Tags: java, android

i want the spash screen to only show when the app has been compltely destroyed not when it is running in the background and resumed

Comment: Your title mentions a splash screen when your application starts up, and then the text mentions when it's "compltely destroyed". Are you referring to a particular activity?

Comment: yes i mean i only want the spash to show when the app is completly closed out and restarted not when the user goes to another pp really quick and comes back taht would be annoying

Comment: you want to do this in onCreate() of your initial activity, based on your descriptions. How/when you start your splash screen will depend on what background activities you're trying to load up.

Comment: Do you really need a splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple method:

Main Activity is only a splash screen.  This Activity is shown while a timer starts that elapses for say 4 seconds.

When 4 seconds hits, the splash screen activity is destroyed and the Main Application Activity is started.

Voila, you now have a splash screen that will never be shown, except when you first start the application.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int time = 0;
                    while (time < 4000) {
                       sleep(100);
                       time += 100;
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainApplication.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: The while-loop in your try-block is unnecessary. Why don't you simply sleep for 4000ms (or how long you want to sleep)?

Answer (score 3):

### Android's Live-Circle

When your Acrivity is created:

1. onCreate
2. onStart
3. onResume

when your Activity becomes inactive:

1. onPause
2. onStop

when it becomes active again:

1. onRestart
2. onStart
3. onResume

and when it's destroyed:

1. onPause
2. onStop
3. onDestroy

**Edit:** what i would do is, i would define a global boolean for your Main-Activity, 'showSpash' for example, and initialize it as "true". Then, when your 'onCreate'-method is first called, you set it to "false".
Then, anytime the 'onCreate'-method is called, you check if the boolean is "false". If it is, don't show the splash, if not show it.

Comment: Changing orientation can trigger a new onCreate call.  I don't think the question asker wants a splash screen for this condition.

Answer (score 2):

I created global variable in my application class:

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {
    public static boolean welcomeScreenIsShown = false;
}
```

Then in my `splash activity` I did something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    //Put this before anything else in OnCreate
    if (MyApplicationClass.welcomeScreenIsShown) {
        // Open your Main Activity
    }
}
```

Then, in my Main Activity, I did:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyApplicationClass.welcomeScreenIsShown = true;
}
```

---

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to set the `android:noHistory="true"` attribute for SplashScreenActivity in the `AndroidManifest`.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this the purpose of "onResume()" vs. "onCreate()"?

Comment: so would i use the on resume and just make it skip the splash?

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand your point.  onResume is called after onCreate, and onCreate is called in situations other than the user newly launching the application, e.g. the user changed screen orientations while the app was running.  Also, onResume can get called *a lot* while the app is in normal use, and it's behavior should be very lightweight.  Please don't put heavy things that belong in onCreate in onResume.

Comment: This does not answer the question.