# Resuming last activity on icon press to set result

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, manifest

I am trying to re-open last activity on icon press. But it starts from splash when I remove launchMode SingleTask from main.

Below is the scenario -
 A = Splash , B = Activity1 , C = Activity 2.

I want to launch C on icon press.

On Start
    A ---->B---->C (Here home icon pressed)
On Click Icon It runs A but I want C . Can any one solve this?

Launching C-

```
Intent urlIntent = new Intent(this,C.class); 
urlIntent.putExtra("stt",Str);
startActivityForResult(urlIntent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757562/how-do-i-show-a-splash-screen-only-when-the-activity-starts-up-not-when-it-is-re

Do you require the splash screen?

Comment: @jL4 splash isn't mandatory and I cant finish previous activity.

Comment: What do you exactly - after put in background when you press your app icon from menu - the last activity will be automatically resumed !!
Or do you want something like after closing your app, when restarted from menu, after clicking on your app icon the last activity should be resumed ?

Comment: @shadygoneinsane I have updated the question I am only trying to open second activity where it was.

Comment: @Banku I have posted an solution. do check and I hope this helps .

Comment: I think you should visit this thread [Android: bug in launchMode=“singleTask”? -> activity stack not preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved)

Comment: Please post your manifest. You may be seeing a nasty long-standing Android bug that has never been fixed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508 for more details and a workaround. To check if you are seeing this bug, install your app on the phone. Kill the app (settings->apps->yourapp->force close). Now start your app from the HOME screen icon. Open ActivityB -> ActivityC. Press HOME. launch your app again by pressing the app icon on the HOME screen. If you see ActivityC you're seeing this nasty bug.

Answer (score 3):

CASE I. Check if your app is in background after pressing the home button. If it is then it should open activity C.

CASE II. If your app is killed due to low on memory then it will start from launcher activity i.e. activity A.

I also faced this issue. This issue occurred due to changed setting of device.If user enable **"Don't keep activities"** then all activities will be destroyed if you press home or start new activity.

Note: I used the default launch mode

[image: Attaching a screen for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Your app will always start from the `Activity` with the filter `intent.action.MAIN` in the Manifest.xml.

And if your application is already running then the next time time your app starts it will automatically resume from the last opened activity.

Now if your app gets killed or swiped out then you can store the activity in `SharedPreferences` when activity is resumed or paused and on next start check in your spash which is `Activity 'A'` in your case, which was the last opened activity as you had stored the `Activity` name in `SharedPreferences`.

Example :

If you have three activities A-->B-->C

store the name in `onPause()` of all activities use `SharedPreference` to store its name :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("lastOpenedActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

And in your Splash which is here `Activity A` use this preference to checfk in your `onCreate()` -

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Class lastActivity;

    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        lastActivity = Class.forName(prefs.getString("lastOpenedActivity", ParentActivity.class.getName()));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        lastActivity = ParentActivity.class;
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(this, lastActivity));
    this.finish();
}
```